# Como puedo mostrar el nombre del producto al insertar codigo de producto

Tags: php, html, ajax

Compra de productos, al insertar código, mostrar el nombre del producto al que pertenece.

Este es el código:

```html
<div class="md-modal md-dark custom-width md-effect-9" id="formnproducto">
  <div class="md-content">
    <div class="modal-header">
      <h3>Compra de Producto</h3>
      <button type="button" class="close md-close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body form">
      
      <form id='fcproducto' name='fcproducto' data-parsley-validate>

       <div class="form-group" id='mproducto' style="display:none">
          <label>Producto</label>
          <select class="form-control" id="producto">
            <option value='0' selected>Seleccionar</option> 
            
          </select>
        </div>
        
      <div class="form-group" id='mcodigo'>
        <label>Código</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" required placeholder="Código" id='codigo' name='codigo' autofocus>
      </div>
      
      
      <div id="clicboton"><span id="btnbuscar" class="btn" onclick="$('#btncancelar').show('slow'); $('#btnbuscar').hide('slow'); $('#mproducto').show('slow'); $('#mcodigo').hide('slow');">Buscar</span><span style="display:none" id="btncancelar" class="btn" onclick="$('#btnbuscar').show('slow'); $('#btncancelar').hide('slow'); $('#mcodigo').show('slow'); $('#mproducto').hide('slow');">Regresar</span></div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Nombre</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" id='nombre' name='nombre' onchange="document.getElementById('').innerHTML = valorname = this.value">
      </div>

      <div class="form-group">
        <label>Cantidad</label> <input type="text" class="form-control" required placeholder="Cantidad" id='cantidad' name='cantidad' value="1">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="cant" class="control-label">Nota</label> <textarea class="form-control" required placeholder="Nota" id='nota' name='nota' rows="3"></textarea>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
      <button type="button" class="btn btn-default btn-flat md-close" data-dismiss="modal">Cancelar</button>
      <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-flat">Aceptar</button>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

*Captura de pantalla:*
[image: Compra de productos, al insertar código, mostrar el nombre del producto al que pertenece]

Comment: ¿Con una llamada AJAX? ¿A que te refieres con "Filtrar"? ¿Tienes una lista en un "drop down menu" y solo los que coincidan con el código se muestren y los demás se eliminen de ese menú?

Comment: Me refiero que al insertar código me muestre el nombre de ese producto, en el input de nombre.,

Comment: @Azteca lo que entiendo es que al buscar un producto por código muestre el resultado de búsqueda en este caso el nombre del producto en el formulario es decir en el input.

Comment: @Alex Ya veo, lo que me confundió fue la palabra "filtrar" que generalmente es seleccionar algo de un grupo según parámetros. Pero no hay nada en el ejemplo

Comment: tal vez no era la palabra correcta "filtrar" pero me han comprendido-..,

Comment: @Azteca Exactamente el título de la pregunta está mal, por eso me confundió igual jaj

Answer (score 1):

Algo así quedaría tu [llamada AJAX](https://api.jquery.com/jquery.get/):

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    $('#clicboton').on('click',buscaNombre);
    function buscaNombre(){
        $.get('url',
            {
                codigo:$('#codigo').value
            },
            function (data,textStatus,xhr){
                $('#nombre').value(data.nombre);
            }
        );
    }
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Si utilizas una llamada `ajax()` podrás enviar el código escrito a una función `php` donde podrás buscar por código el producto y retornar el nombre del producto.

Ejemplo:

```
// obtenemos el codigo insertado preferentemente colocar un id al input código
var _codigo= $('#mcodigo').val();

$.ajax({
            type: 'post',
            data: 'buscarcodigo?codigo='+_codigo,
            dataType: 'html',
            success: function(data){
            $('#nombre').val(data.valor);// colocamos el nombre al campo requerido

      }
});
```

Comment: y como quedaría la función en php para realizar la busqueda